# telepresence: error: connector.Connect: kubeconfig has no context definition

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, telepresence

Unable to connect to k8s with telepresence. I using minikube as my util to manage k8s and using telepresence to develop my code with k8s. Sometimes it will work, but sometimes I cann't connect to k8s.

The command I used.

```sh
# start the k8s
minikube start
# connect
telepresence connect
```

Fail to connect to k8s with `telepresence connect`

```
Launching Telepresence Root Daemon
Launching Telepresence User Daemon
Telepresence Root Daemon quitting... done
Telepresence User Daemon is already stopped
telepresence: error: connector.Connect: kubeconfig has no context definition
```

Comment: When you run `kubectl config get-contexts` what does it return?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.
So, I tried with different version.

In my case, v2.5.8 works well.